# Input Mask for only alpha characters let 1 words only with Primeng in Angular

Tags: html, angular, primeng

Like tutorial said "`a - Alpha character (defaut: A-Z,a-z)`" that's ok.

But when I am applying `mask="a"` like below it just let me enter 1 word but i dont wanna restrict the size of input.So people can enter any size word to it.
How can i achieve that ?

I tried with `characterPattern="[А-Zа-z]"` or giving normal html pattern property with regular expresiion like `^[A-Za-z]` but didn't work.Thanks in advance

```
<p-inputMask mask="a" [placeholder]="'gerekli' | translate" [(ngModel)]="User.adi"></p-inputMask>
```

Comment: Hey there. Did you try doing `<p-inputMask mask="a*" [placeholder]="'gerekli' | translate" [(ngModel)]="User.adi"></p-inputMask>` ?

Comment: Yea mask property take * for alpha numeric characters.so if i using it i can have 2 alpha and numeric characters at all. So its not working like i expected

Comment: It's not a good way but onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                    event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) " i did like this

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the following,

In your component.ts file,

```
setInputFilter(inputHTML, inputValue) {
    [
      "input",
      "keyup",
      "keydown",
      "mouseup",
      "mousedown",
      "select",
      "contextmenu",
      "drop"
    ].forEach(function(event) {
      inputHTML.addEventListener(event, function() {
        if (inputValue(this.value)) {
          this.previousValue = this.value;
          this.previousSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
          this.previousSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
        } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("previousValue")) {
          this.value = this.previousValue;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Call the function `setInputFilter` inside `AfterViewInit` life-cycle hook.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.setInputFilter(document.getElementById("inputText"), function (value) {

      return /^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(value);

    })
  }
```

In your component.html file,

```
<input id="inputText" pInputText [(ngModel)]="val"/>
```

I am using `InputTextModule` of PrimeNG instead of `InputMaskModule`